# Extracting variable name as string in a Spatial Polygons Data Frame

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial

I need to write a function that omits NA values from a Spatial Polygons Data Frame, but only for a single column. I am currently using

`sp.na.omit(col.name= )`

The issue is that the input in the function is of the format

```
spatialdf$variable
```

and to work the function needs the variable name as a string, i.e. `"variable"`.
I cannot seem to find a way to extrapolate `variable` out of `spatialdf$variable`.

`select()` from `dplyr` does not work because it is a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
library(sp)
library(spatialEco)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y

myfunction <- function (data, variable){
  data <- sp.na.omit(data, col.name = variable)
}

myfunction(meuse, "zinc")
```

My issue is that for the function that I am currently using, "zinc" has to be entered as meuse$zinc in all other instances, but for this specific instance i need it to be as a string.

How do I take meuse$zinc and get "zinc"?

I would greatly appreciate any help

Comment: I am a bit confused, but have you tried `spatialdf[, "variable"]`? Perhaps include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I added the example.

Comment: You can try this: `myfunction <- function (data, variable) as.data.frame(data)[variable]` and then `myfunction(meuse, "zinc")`